# Schema to use for general web pages

Tags: microdata

I am implementing Schema across my website I am remodeling.

I am trying to determine which schema to use for general webpages. These pages contain general information about the company and other information that is not specific articles. For these pages which schema should I use?

Looking at the schema website it seems that the following could apply:

- [Website](http://schema.org/WebSite)
- [Webpage](http://schema.org/WebPage)
- [Article](http://schema.org/Article)

Which would be best to use for a page that contains information but is not a specific article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the website is a organization or local business then you should opt to use either: [organization](http://schema.org/Organization) or [local business](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) combined with things like [products](http://schema.org/Product) and [services](https://schema.org/Service). Many online businesses use lcoal markup in the footer and company name at the top meaning that schema is repeated on every page, then in the content area you use products or services which differs on every other page apart from the home page. You can then use article for the [blog](http://schema.org/Article) pages of the website.

It's important to note that there's many ways this can be approached and you should use the one best fit for your website.

Answer (score 3):

There are usually two "levels" of your web page that can be marked up with Schema.org (note that I made these levels up for this answer; the difference is not always useful):

- level 1: the web page itself (i.e., the transport medium)
- level 2: the content/entities contained in the web page

Obviously, *every* web page can be marked up with [WebPage](http://schema.org/WebPage) (or one of its more specific types). Welcome to level 1. With such markup, you are specifying 1.) that it’s a web page, and, if you use a more specific type, 2.) what kind of web page it is. Note that having this markup is not necessary, and consumers like search engines are often more interested in level 2.

With level 2, you specify what the page is about, and what entities it contains/mentions. This can be everything, starting from [Thing](http://schema.org/Thing).

In your question, you give this example for "general web pages":

> These pages contain general information about the company and other information that is not specific articles.

For a page containing "general information about the company", it might be appropriate to use the [AboutPage](http://schema.org/AboutPage) (level 1). And because this page is about a company, it might be appropriate to use [Organization](http://schema.org/Organization) (level 2).
If you want to use only one item on your page, use `Organization`.

For specifying what the `WebPage` is about, you could use the [`about` property](http://schema.org/about):

```
WebPage → about → Organization
```

The next Schema.org version will also contain the properties `mainEntity` ([draft](http://sdo-gozer.appspot.com/mainEntity)) and `mainEntityOfPage` ([draft](http://sdo-gozer.appspot.com/mainEntityOfPage)).

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Article schema. Especially if you have are planning to have a blog.

If there are specific pages,I'd also include LocalBusiness in the About us / Contact us pages.